# HorizontalScrollView android Doesnt work very well

Tags: android, size, width, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Good morning everybody

I have a problem with an HorizontalScrollView.

I see all the textview in a horizontal linearlayout but at the end happend a problem.

The horizontalScrollView is unable to display all the information, there is like a cut of the view...why?

is there a maximun size of the horizontalScrollView maybe?

a part of code xml

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:id="@+id/hrz_scroll"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <!--  Header  Starts-->
            <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/MostraRigheInserzioneActivity_layout_linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">    
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

print screen

[image]

help me 
best regards

Comment: Please post your code!!!

Comment: <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

Comment: Could you give us more xml code? (parents and childs)

Comment: Post screenshot so that one can get idea of your problem.

Comment: Post whole xml code...

Comment: i update with the code

Comment: i update with a print screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this for your concern

```
  <HorizontalScrollView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:id="@+id/hrz_scroll"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         >
```

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:id="@+id/hrz_scroll"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <!--  Header  Starts-->
            <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/MostraRigheInserzioneActivity_layout_linearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">    
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, no problem with the horizontal scroll, maybe its a problem of the layout that not contain all information?

Comment: why you are putting horizontal scroll in Scroll view

Comment: it doesnt work but now i put a printscreen in the original ask